# MATLAB Equation as User Input to work with

Tags: matlab, function, input

I'm trying to write a simple script that request a equation as input and I like to calculate with this function more than once without always requesting user input.

My current script defined f as function handle and executed the function 2 times, so I'm always asking for a new equation, which is not desirable.

```
f = @(x) input('f(x) = ');
a = f(2);   % requests user input
b = f(3);   % requests user input again
```

And it should look more like this (not working).

```
func = input('f(x) = ');
f = @(x) func;
a = f(2);
b = f(3);
```

And here without user input to get an idea what I try to achieve.

```
f = @(x) x^2;
a = f(2);
b = f(3);
```

I think I found a solution with Symbolic Math Toolbox, but I do not have this addon, so I cannot use/test it.

Is there another solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need for the Symbolic Mathematics Toolbox here.  You can still use `input`.  Bear in mind that the default method of [`input`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/input.html) is to directly take the input and assign it as a variable where the input is assumed to be syntactically correct according to MATLAB rules.  That's not what you want.  You'll want to take the input as a **string** by using the `'s'` option as the second parameter then use [`str2func`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2func.html) to convert the string into an anonymous function:

```
func = input('f(x) = ', 's');
f = str2func(['@(x) ' func]);
a = f(2);
b = f(3);
```

Take note that I had to concatenate the `@(x)` anonymous function string with the inputted function you provided with `input`.

## Example Run

Let's say I want to create a function that squares every element in the input:

```
>> func = input('f(x) = ', 's');
f(x) = x.^2
>> f = str2func(['@(x) ' func])

f = 

    @(x)x.^2

>> a = f(2)

a =

     4

>> b = f(3)

b =

     9
```

Take special note that I assumed the function will **element-wise** square each elements in the input.  The `.` operator in front of the exponentiation operator (i.e. `^`) is very important.